# Is removing 'explicit' from a constructor binary compatible?

Tags: c++, c++03, explicit-constructor

An external library we are using contains the following explicit constructor:

```
class Chart {
public:
    explicit Chart(Chart::Type type, Object *parent);
    // ...
};
```

The compiler complains with the following warning:

```
chart.h: warning #2305: declaration of 'explicit' constructor
without a single argument is redundant
```

Is it binary compatible to just remove the `explicit` keyword in chart.h without recompiling the library to avoid the warning? My feeling is that it's safe, since `explicit` does not make sense in this case anyways. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Turn off stupid warnings.

Comment: I guess this is the best advice :-)

Comment: The warning used to make perfect sense pre-c++11. If your compiler is pre-c++11, you may encounter more serious problems with c++11 code, so you probably should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet by a country mile is to switch off that warning for the duration of that inclusion if you get my meaning. **Don't** hack the vendor code.

Using `explicit` for multi-argument constructors makes perfect sense in C++11 onwards since it can be used to stop implicit brace initialisation. Futhermore the standard *doesn't* say that removing `explicit` must preserve the *layout* of the class, so you must assume that removing `explicit` *could* break binary compatibility. Also, dropping it *could* change the behaviour of contrived SFINAE patterns as that constructor could become re-available in certain circumstances. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae.

Answer (score 2):

`explicit` makes sense with multiple parameters in the context of brace-initializers in C++11 and above:

```
void foo(Chart const &);

// ...

// Will only compile without `explicit`
foo({Chart::Type::pie, myObj});
```

Whether it is binary-compatible to remove `explicit` ultimately depends on your compiler, so you'd have to find that in its documentation.

However, since `explicit` is a high-level language feature that only pilots overload resolution, I wouldn't expect it to break compatibility *as long as it doesn't change what the best match is for some pre-existing call, including inside any code that you compile from the library itself (templates and/or inline functions)*.

That said, this is pure ad-hoc patching : according to the Standard, doing that flings you straight into UB territory. Quoting from [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m)'s comment:

> Fiddling with headers like that breaks ODR. Vendor's binaries are compiled with a certain definition of a class, your binaries are compiled with a different definition of the same class. That's illegal. It doesn't matter how small the change is. The definitions must be token-by-token identical, period.

I'd recommend to simply silence the warning in these headers, by wrapping them in `#pragma`s where included (or in a custom proxy header, and include that).

Comment: UV'd. But as for "Whether it is binary-compatible to remove explicit ultimately depends on your compiler, so you'd have to find that in its documentation." we are in contradiction here. My understanding is that `explicit` is not allowed to affect the `struct` layout. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @Bathsheba about the layout I don't know, but `explicit` might for example participate in name mangling, and change the constructor's procedure name. I admit it's a bit of a stretch for me to say that nothing is guaranteed without having read the whole Standard, but I doubt there's a section about that, so... safety first!

Comment: @Batsheba Fiddling with headers like that breaks ODR. Vendor's binaries are compiled with a certain definition of a class, your binaries are compiled with a different definition of the same class. That's illegal. It doesn't matter how small the change is. The definitions must be token-by-token identical, period. The compiler can incorporate a hash of the definition in symbol names, for all we know.